# play a dynamic sound file in asterisk musiconhold

Tags: audio, asterisk, ivr

I have used asterisk [MusicOnHold](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MusicOnHold) with that I have to point a particlar folder in `musiconhold.conf` and during the execution all the tone inside that folder are played for all the users.

But now I have to play a specific sound file for each user uploaded by them.My problem is that how can I play this file for user.Because if he uploads a sound file then I have to manually create a class in `musiconhold.conf` pointing to that folder the do `moh reload`.

I just want to automate the things to the user just uploads the sound file and during the call of that user in `extensions.conf`  I can point to that sound file and it will be played without reload or adding context in `musiconhold.conf` everytime.

For ex. the way `Playback(pathToSoundfil)` works which takes tone path directly is there any function like in musiconhold for directly passing the sound file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do as many section in your musiconhold file as you want.

After that you can use thoose class

No, you can't change classes without reload res_musiconhold

However you can use asterisk realtime architecture and put whole config into mysql. Still need do script which will do reload.

If you want 100% realtime solution, you can use conference and play into same conference any file. Just create enother call to conference which play file. This variant require expert level in asterisk.

Comment: well I am not an expert. What exactly my problem is when usig the playback the code stops at playback command play the tone and move on which is sequential I want a way some background tone which will execute while the code in executing and the call is forwarding is there any way?

Comment: Background app play while collect digits. m option for dial play moh while call out. For other action need use chanspy or conferences and complex dialplan.